# Store Dynamic list/array in database using python

Tags: python, arrays, database, variables

I crawl some online data from web using python, store array in variable now want to store in database dynamically, How can i do this, I am beginner and totally new in python, here is the code

```
car_version = [item.find(class_='version-name').get_text() for item in cars]

car_price = [item.find(class_='version-price generic-green').get_text() for item in cars]

print(car_version)
print(car_price)
```

output of the print command is like this

```
['Honda Accord 2.4 i-VTEC Prosmatec', 'Honda City i-VTEC', 'Honda Civic VTi 1.8 i-VTEC']

['PKR 14,500,000', 'PKR 27,500,000', 'PKR 32,500,000']
```

```
sql = """CREATE TABLE MARKETRATE (
                 id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                 carName VARCHAR(255),
                 carPrice VARCHAR(255)
                 )"""
mycursor.execute(sql)

sql1 = "INSERT INTO MARKETRATE(carName, carPrice) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = [ (car_version, car_price)]

   mycursor.execute(sql1, val)
   print('inserted')
mydb.close()
```

How to store array using python?
Need help.

Answer (score 0):

To enter the data into the database so that you have four rows, you need to [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together, then pass the sql statement and the zipped value to the cursor's [executemany](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany) method.  Zipping the two lists creates an iterable of (version, price) [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).  `executemany` will generate INSERT statements for each pair.

```
vals = zip(version, price)
# print(list(zip(version, price)))
# [('Honda Accord 2.4 i-VTEC Prosmatec', 'PKR 14,500,000'), ('Honda City i-VTEC', 'PKR 27,500,000'), ('Honda Civic VTi 1.8 i-VTEC', 'PKR 32,500,000')]                                                                    
mycursor.executemany(sql1, vals)                                                                                                                                  
mydb.commit()
```